# Deleting data from access database

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, ms-access

```
    con = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(Con_String)
    cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("delete from Accessed_DB where pathofdb =@pathofdb", con)
    con.Open()
    cmd.Parameters.RemoveAt("@pathofdb")
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MsgBox("Record Deleted")
    con.Close()
```

I am using above code to delete data but it not get successful. why?

Comment: By `not successful`. What do you mean? Are getting an error or it is not getting deleted with no errors or something else? Add these details, the error and how to replicate the error to your question by editing it.

Answer (score 2):

```
cmd.Parameters.RemoveAt("@pathofdb")
```

should probably be

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pathofdb", "some path")
```

Having said that I don't think OLEDB supports named arguments in the SQL syntax so I think your command should be:

```
  cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("delete from Accessed_DB where pathofdb =?", con)
```

Comment: While named arguments are not supported, using a name makes coding easier, as long as you remember that it is the position, not the name that is important. Good answer, anyway.